# Swift compiler: Printing the AST of a Swift file with 3rd party imports

Tags: ios, swift, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to [print the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) from a Swift file](http://ankit.im/swift/2016/02/29/swift-abstract-syntax-tree/) using the Swift compiler with the `-print-ast` flag. This is without Xcode & `xcodebuild`.

I'm stuck handling imports of 3rd party frameworks, built via Carthage. Given a source file with the following code:

#### Source

```swift
import Foundation
import BrightFutures // 3rd party framework

class MyAsyncService {
    func asyncFunc() -> Future<String, NSError> {
        return Promise<String, NSError>().future
    }
}
```

#### Compiling for MacOS works

By specifying the framework search path (`-F`) the following command:

```
swiftc -print-ast Source.swift -F Carthage/Build/Mac
```

Produces the expected output:

```
import Foundation
import BrightFutures

internal class MyAsyncService {
  internal func asyncFunc() -> Future<String, NSError>
  @objc deinit
  internal init()
}
```

#### Compiling for iOS?

I need to print the AST for a project only targeting iOS, with dependencies built for iOS.

When I try pointing to the frameworks built for iOS:

```
swiftc -print-ast Source.swift -F Carthage/Build/iOS
```

The command fails:

```
Source.swift:2:12: error: module file was created for incompatible target x86_64-apple-ios8.0: [...]/Carthage/Build/iOS/BrightFutures.framework/Modules/BrightFutures.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
    import BrightFutures // 3rd party framework
           ^
import Foundation
import BrightFutures

internal class MyAsyncService {
  internal func asyncFunc() -> <<error type>>
  @objc deinit
  internal init()
}
```

I've tried also tried adding the `-sdk` flag:

`-sdk $(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path)` to [specify the iphoneos SDK](https://coderwall.com/p/heonhw/compiling-for-ios-outside-of-xcode-with-xcrun), but this spits out an error about unsupported architectures.

How can I get this to build?

Comment: set -target to any of these: x86_64-apple-ios8.0 / i386-apple-ios8.0 / armv7-apple-ios8.0 / arm64-apple-ios8.0.
set -sdk as well.
without providing sdk path swiftc builds for native tripple i.e osx [i386 / x86_64].
your framework target should match with the -target you provide to swift compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an alternative to printing the AST with the Swift compiler is to use [SourceKit](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/tools/SourceKit).

There's a CLI tool called [SourceKitten](https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten) which allows you to parse the structure of a Swift source file into JSON format, without needing to handle imports of 3rd party frameworks and other source files.